# How do I display a summary of items in a cart from a $_SESSION onto another page

Tags: php, html, session

I need my cart page to show a summary "line item" like view of all vending machines purchased on my vend page  with $_SESSION['cart']

Here is my code which allows me to add multiple items to the cart: (Vend Page)

```
 session_start();

 //Check if $_SESSION['cart] exists
 if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {

 //initiate cart as empty array      
    $_SESSION['cart'] = [];
 }

 if (isset($_POST['add'])) {

 //add product id to session cart
 $_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['add']] =1;
 }

 else if (isset($_POST['remove'])) {

    //remove product id from session cart
    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['remove']]);
}
```

I just need a way to display the items I "Add to Cart" on the Vend Page" to display in a list onto another page "Cart page". Ive made an image to show how it should be displayed:  [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyVIO.png)

Comment: Unclear what you are asking; what is the actual _problem_ you are having with this?

Comment: Im asking how I can do it, I'm not sure on how to start

Comment: What, you have never heard of the different ways to loop over the contents of an array …? Then why are you working on any kind of web shop functionality already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your cart page add this -

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $name => $price){
    echo $name . " - " . $price;
 }
}else{
// optional(if cart is empty it will redirect to another page)
  header("location:products.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $name => $price){
        echo $name . " - " . $price;
    }
}
```